# SELECT "sum, count, fields" with 2 tables joined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to convert this query using symbols and table_name cause my DB isn't in rails standard.

```
SELECT v.taux, sum(v.basevat) as tax, sum(v.valuevat) as amountvat, count(t.id)
FROM vatsomething as v
INNER JOIN somethingreceipt as t
ON v.uid_receipt = t.uid
WHERE t.cancelled = 0
GROUP BY v.taux
ORDER BY v.taux ASC;

class Vat < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "vatsomething"
  alias_attribute :base, :basevat
  alias_attribute :value, :valuevat
  alias_attribute :rate, :taux
  belongs_to :receipt, foreign_key: 'uid_receipt', primary_key: 'uid'
end

class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "somethingreceipt"
  has_many :item, foreign_key: 'uid_receipt', primary_key: 'uid'
end
```

I don't have the choice, if I divide this query to 4 queries, it's too slow.

I tried some queries :

```
Vat.joints(:receipt).
select(:rate, sum(:base), sum(:value), count(Receipt.table_name.:id) ).
where(Receipt.table_name => hash_of_conds.rejectblank)
```

I've tried quickly with pluck but I don't know if I can use symbols.

I understand that my query is really hard and the non standard db doesn't help.

Maybe, I'll have to use `const_get`...

Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use the more railsy methods very easily with legacy databases in rails. Your queries will have to end up being more SQL for this to function correctly. (I have run into this a lot with people that want to keep their DB but run it on rails)

Have you tried this

```
Vat.joins(:receipt).where("somethingreceipt.cancelled = 0").
group("vatsomething.taux").
select("vatsomething.taux as rate,
         sum(vatsomething.basevat) as tax, 
         sum(vatsomething.valuevat) as amountvat,
         count(somethingreceipt.id) as receipt_count").
order("vatsomething.taux")
```

This should return your desired result.

You have to remember that aliasing methods does not alter the names in the table when running queries you will still have to use the legacy table names and column names.

You can then access the attributes of each object in the `ActiveRecord::Relation` though their as names e.g. (`#rate`,`#tax`,`#amountvat`,`#receipt_count`)

Scoping option great for legacy DB's to keep your specific queries consolidated inside the model making it easier to make changes without having to find these queries all over the application.

```
class Vat

   scope :receipt_summary, ->(conditions){
        joins(:receipt).where(conditions).
        group("vatsomething.taux").
        select("vatsomething.taux as rate,
               sum(vatsomething.basevat) as tax, 
               sum(vatsomething.valuevat) as amountvat,
               count(somethingreceipt.id) as receipt_count").
        order("vatsomething.taux")
        }
end
```

Then you can call `Vat.receipt_summary("somethingreceipt.cancelled = 0")` or even should be able to call `Vat.receipt_summary({receipt:{cancelled:0}})`

Comment: Thank you, I tried this query but if I change my DB, I'll have to change every queries of this type. It's not acceptable.

Comment: @Alexis_user First did it work for you? Second unfortunately I believe that is where you are stuck. Accept that you must do this or create a new DB and migrate the data accordingly. :( Like I said legacy DB's are tough with rails unless you are willing to put in the extra work.

Comment: Ok, but even if I migrate my db, there isn't any solution without put the real name of tables. I'm going to accept this.

Comment: @Alexis_user There are some fairly manageable ways of consolidating these types of queries. Like `scoping` which is what I would recommend that way when/if you make a change you don't have to run around all over looking for these queries you can keep them in scopes inside `Vat` and change them there and it will change everywhere I have added an example.

Comment: Ok ! I didn't know `scoping`, thank you again ! I know more of Rails now.